# Permutations of multisets

Tags: dart, recursion

I'm trying to calculate the permutation of the word banana, but the code I made calculates it incorrectly, it doesn't take into account the letters that are repeated in the word, in words that the letters are not repeated works normally.

```
List<String> permute(String word, int l, int r) {
  List<String> output = [];
  if (l == r) {
    print(word);
    output.add(word);
  } else {
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
      word = swap(word, l, i);
      output = output + permute(word, l + 1, r);
      word = swap(word, l, i);
    }
  }
  return output;
}

String swap(String a, int i, int j) {
  List<String> charArray = a.split('');
  String temp = '';

  temp = charArray[i];
  charArray[i] = charArray[j];
  charArray[j] = temp;
  return charArray.join();
}
```

In my current code I get 720 possibilities, but according to the [calculators](https://getcalc.com/statistics-letters-permutations.htm) it should be 60 because of the letters that are repeated, how can I solve this?

Comment: If you just want the *number* of permutations, you can compute that without actually generating all permutations: 6!/(3!*2!).  Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2324369/

Comment: What is your goal? If it's just to find all the combinations, collect them in a set instead of a list, that should remove duplicates. If the goal is to never generate the duplicates to begin with, you need more cleverness (like counting occurrences of each character first, then build words recursively by choosing each of the available letters as the first one, in turn, decrement its count, and continue with the remaining combinations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that if you filter the list before returning the problem is solved

```
return output.toSet().toList();

or

if (!output.contains(word)) {
  output = output + permute(word, l + 1, r);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<T>> getPermutations<T extends Object>(List<T> list) {
  if (list.length > 2) {
    var _result = <List<T>>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var _set = list.toList();
      var _e = _set.removeAt(i);
      _result.addAll(getPermutations(_set).map((e) => e..insert(0, _e)));
    }
    return _result;
  }
  if (list.length < 2) return [list];

  return [list, [list[1],list[0]]];
}

void makePermutationsFrom(String word) {
  final result = getPermutations(word.split('')).map((e) => e.join()).toSet();
  print(result.length);
  print(result);
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  makePermutationsFrom('banana');
}
```

Output:

```
60
{banana, banaan, bannaa, baanna, baanan, baaann, bnaana, bnaaan, bnanaa, bnnaaa, abnana, abnaan, abnnaa, abanna, abanan, abaann, anbana, anbaan, anbnaa, anabna, anaban, ananba, ananab, anaabn, anaanb, annbaa, annaba, annaab, aabnna, aabnan, aabann, aanbna, aanban, aannba, aannab, aanabn, aananb, aaabnn, aaanbn, aaannb, nbaana, nbaaan, nbanaa, nbnaaa, nabana, nabaan, nabnaa, naabna, naaban, naanba, naanab, naaabn, naaanb, nanbaa, nanaba, nanaab, nnbaaa, nnabaa, nnaaba, nnaaab}
```